# socket.io - How to check if the client has connected from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

What is the most reliable way to detect if some one has directly connect to my socket connection instead of browser? I know that we can bypass all of that but I realized some WebSockets like tradingView return 403 when connecting directly from `socket.io-client` but works fine from browser.

How does it detect that And How can I implement that for my own socket.io server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get device/browser/app the client is connected with but I managed to do something like that using handshake query of socket.io. I needed to distinguish between admin and client so in my client side I used this code:

```js
 const socket = io({
        query: {
            isAdmin: true,
            name: "GetSub Admin"
        },
        // path: '/websockets',
        resource: '/websockets'
    });
```

and on the server side I used

```js
if (client.handshake.query.isAdmin == 'true') {
            admins.push({
                id: client.id,
                name: client.handshake.query.name
            });
        }
        else {
            users.push({
                id: client.id,
                name: client.handshake.query.name
            });
```

maybe this will help you.